# How do i create the above view in my android application?

Tags: java, android, xml

Because i'm create an app similar to what was shown below but i have no idea how to create a view similar to what was shown above after i click a buttton to navigate to this page where all the video and map log file is shown..
I'm kinna new in android/java can someone guide me on this?

EDIT: This is a series of code for creating a directory to store my video files but these files can only be seen outside the application but i wanted it to be seen in the application where when a button is pressed it navigates to the VideoList to browse the various videa file i have filmed and when press it display a custom screen seen [here](http://www.google.com.sg/imglanding?q=autoguard%20blackbox&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us%3aIE-Address&rlz=1I7ADFA_en&tbm=isch&tbnid=V7qe7Ei5QW7BgM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.androidapps.com/apps/435160-autoguard-blackbox-hovan-yoo&imgurl=http://c1345842.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/assets/screenshots/images/002/558/790/original.jpg%253F1298353539&w=480&h=800&ei=B-S4TYrjN_Pp0QGT3c2DCg&zoom=1&iact=hc&page=4&tbnh=159&tbnw=95&start=69&ndsp=24&ved=1t:429,r:22,s:69&biw=1366&bih=653). But what are the things should be done to achieve this?

```
File dirlist = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/VideoList");
if(!(dirlist.exists()))    
dirlist.mkdir();
File TempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()                     + "/VideoList", dateFormat.format(date) + fileFormat);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(TempFile.getPath());
```

Comment: You want to create a video player view. Right?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay Zack its a custom Dialog check out this... code

**main.xml**(Your main page layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="This is my main activity, from here, I want to display a dialog, after the user clicked the button below this text.">
</TextView>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/Button01main"
android:text="Hey! There is more..."></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**maindialog.xml**(Your Dialog layout page)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView01"
android:layout_height="200px">
 <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
<Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_below="@id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:text="Cancel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**dilo.java**(Display dialog on click button code)

```
package com.example.dilo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class dilo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button1main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01main);

        button1main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                //set up dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(dilo.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
                dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                //there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!
                //set up text
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                text.setText(R.string.lots_of_text);
                //set up image view
                ImageView img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                //set up button
                Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it   
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

   }
}
```

i think it should help you .... ok... N joy

Comment: @Sanal MS you were quite right, i wanted to display a video List view which each individual file is shown and when click it shows some sort like a log screen which i could click and it shows the custom screen which can be seen in the link provided above..

Comment: but i would want the view from behind which were video file populated onto the listview dynamically.. How should i create the listview that was behind the custom dialog?

Answer (score 0):

zack it is custom dialog u need to create custom dialog

for more info.. go this [link 1)](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application) [link 2](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example)